# How do I modify table data to remove duplicates and "condense" horizontally in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, databricks

I am working in Databricks > Python /w Pandas. I want to restrucure the data to move from:

| ID | Account | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | 4437935470 |
| 1234 | 1 | 4437935470 |
| 1234 | 2 | 4437935472 |
| 1234 | 2 | 4437935473 |
| 1235 | 3 | 4437935474 |
| 1235 | 4 | 4437935475 |
| 1236 | 4 | 4437935476 |
| 1236 | 4 | 4437935477 |

To:

| ID | Account | Phone 1 | Phone 2 | Phone 3 | Phone N etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | 4437935470 | null/empty/etc | null/empty/etc |  |
| 1234 | 2 | 4437935472 | 4437935473 | null/empty/etc |  |
| 1235 | 3 | 4437935474 | null/empty/etc | null/empty/etc |  |
| 1235 | 4 | 4437935475 | 4437935476 | 4437935477 |  |

Ideally, this could all be done using Pandas Dataframe functions. I have limited experience within the data world and with Python/Pandas specifically, so I would consider other options within the context of Databricks / Python approach, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is enssentially pivot with two columns, except that you need to remove duplicates. Read more on [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe). Try:

```
(df.drop_duplicates(['ID','Account','Phone'])
   .assign(col=df.groupby(['ID','Account']).cumcount()+1)
   .set_index(['ID','Account','col'])
   ['Phone'].unstack().add_prefix('Phone ')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output (note that there is a typo in your sample data vs. the expected output):

```
col    ID Account     Phone 1     Phone 2     Phone 3
0    1234       1  4437935470         NaN         NaN
1    1234       2  4437935472  4437935473         NaN
2    1235       3  4437935474         NaN         NaN
3    1236       4  4437935475  4437935476  4437935477
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'cumcount'

Comment: Make sure that `df` is a Pandas dataframe, not some `databricks` thingies. Sorry I'm not familiar with `databricks`, you need to figure that part out.

Comment: I ran an info on the object before executing your code modified with my headers and I get this: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. Thanks for the speedy replies!